# Disable SSL verify for Ubuntu Make

Tags: firefox, firewall, ssl, ubuntu-make

I am trying to install firefox-dev via ubuntu make, and I'm getting an SSL verification error:

```
ERROR: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/all couldn't finish download: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:720)
ERROR: An error occurred while downloading https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/all: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:720)
```

I've run into similar issues before, and I believe it has to do with a company firewall. I've been able to circumvent this issue in the past by disabling SSL verify, for example,

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

Is there a way to do this for Ubuntu Make?

Comment: As far as I understand, the problem is a self-signed certificate of a company. You probably want to add it to trusted list, e.g. [something like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90450/adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-the-trusted-list).